Auth facade with custom data not persistent
I have an array data from API that I want to use in the whole project. I know I can use session but I want
to use Auth facade to take advantage of some of its functions.
First, I make a middleware to get data from API and store it in the User class, then login with Auth facade, then continue to controller
I call it AccountAuthen.php:
$contractInfo = [
    'contract' => 'SGA123123',
    'name'     => 'John Doe',
];
$user = new \App\Http\User($contractInfo);
auth()->login($user);
return $next($request);

Second, I make a User class:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;


    protected $contract;

    public function __construct($data = [])
    {
        $this->contract = $data ?? null;
    }

    // Các phương thức bắt buộc của AuthenticatableContract
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'contract';
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->contract;
    }
}

Finally, I try to get the data in the controller:
auth()->user()->contract;
Problem is I can only get the data in the controller with middleware, if in other controller without middleware, it returns null. I expected that I can get the data in the whole project.
Can you give me some advice on how to solve this problem?

If the user is not logged in, you won't be able to get the logged in user via auth()->user(). In the other controllers, how is a user logged in?

Seems like something you should be persisting to the database and calling as a relationship on your user model.

why not just set the contract value after you login? like auth()->user()->contract = $data ? For this to work you will need to run auth middleware before this middleware.
